# При подключении slick slider, box-shadow на элементах уже не тот (см. скрин)

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js, slider-slick.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

box-shadow сам по себе вот такой (картинка выше)

При добавлении слайдера, он становится вот таким:
Я про серые участки между слайдами. Почему так происходит и как исправить, чтобы было как на первом скрине?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код - кода не будет... на кодпене траблы со слайдами (хоть jq и slick поставил). Может хоть так будет помощь, мб сталкивался кто?

Comment: Тебя беспокоит что тени слайдов сливаются или то что они обрезаются высотой оборачивающего элемента ?

Comment: сливаются, но уже вроде как решил, поставив не 50пх, а 20пх. Если есть предложения - слушаю

Comment: Для начало нужно добавить расстояние между карточками, или же укоротить тень

Comment: ну вот как раз я её укоротил, а расстояние между ними и так есть